# Concurrent simple requests to mongodb drastically slow

Tags: node.js, mongodb

On local dev machine with mongodb v4.0.10 installed I do the following ten concurrent simple requests to a small collection from nodejs app:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/my-db')
  .then(async client => {
    const db = client.db()
    const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]
    await Promise.all(
      list.map(_ => {
        const start = new Date()
        return db
          .collection('orders')
          .find({})
          .toArray()
          .then(() => {
            console.log('passed', new Date() - start)
          })
      })
    )
  })
  .catch()
```

result is

```
passed 10
passed 2012
passed 2013
passed 4018
passed 4018
passed 4019
passed 6042
passed 6043
passed 6045
```

I wonder why I get such a result: only the first request is very quick, others come slower and slower drastically?

I believe there should be some basic issue. MongoDB is configured to be a replica set with a single node (dev machine).

The collection has only 3 elements. it is just for tests purposes. The problem is with concurrency if those requests made in sequence they all take < 10ms

**UPD what I found out:**

1) if to set poolSize: 1 (one), result will be quite ok:

```
passed 12
passed 8
passed 8
passed 15
passed 21
passed 22
passed 22
passed 23
passed 23
```

2) if to use the driver before 3.2.4 result is ok too, but if to increase `poolSize` for old driver second query too becomes slow.

Comment: How big is your orders collection? Does it have any indexes on it? My guess is that you are iterating arbitrarily and then serializing the results of your query into an Array each time. Because you're returning this as an aggregate with Promise.all, each of those iterations are kept in memory. 

It may not seem like it would be a lot, but it does depend on how big the collection is and whether it is doing a full `COLSCAN` each time. 

What results do you get if you remove the .toArray() ?

Comment: the collection has only 3 elements!! it is just for tests purposes. The problem is with concurrency if those requests made in sequence they all take < 10ms

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the output you're seeing. It's constantly `passed xx` where `xx` is around 20 or so. What version of the MongoDB driver are you using, and what's your OS?

Comment: @kevinadi what dirver version you are using this behavior I see starting from 3.2.4

Answer (score 0):

You could try increasing your connection pool size in the connection configuration like so:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/my-db', { poolSize: 10 }).then( ... )
```

MongoDB will throttle the number of concurrent request sessions based on the configured poolSize. A higher poolsize might perform better on good hardware where there are many concurrent requests to the DB, however, it will perform much poorer on average hardware with many concurrent requests.

What output do you get now?

Comment: I tried this, no there result is the same even if I have only 2 concurrent requests, second is slow.